# Check there were no errors in the browser console with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor

I'm using Protractor to test AngularJS

I want to check that at the end of the test no uncaught exceptions occurred and were printed to the browser console.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're using Protractor with Jasmine, use the following code:

```
afterEach(function() {
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
        expect(browserLog.length).toEqual(0);
    });
});
```

This will pass the test case if there are no console errors. If there are any console errors, the test will fail.

Instructions on how to access the content of the browser's console can be found in the [**How can I get hold of the browser's console**](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-get-hold-of-the-browsers-console) section of the FAQ.

Answer (score 16):

*Protractor 2.0.0* [has introduced](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1916) a new `console` plugin specifically for the task.

Add the following to the protractor configuration:

```
plugins: [{
    path: '/path/to/node_modules/protractor/plugins/console/index.js',
    failOnWarning: true,
    failOnError: true
}],
```

Comment: Since 2015 it seems to have moved into a separate 
protractor-plugin-console package for npm

Answer (score 1):

With a little effort we can tweak the accepted answer to work with Cucumber.js, in case you're not using Protractor with the default testing framework.

```
this.After(function(callback) {
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
        if (browserLog.length !== 0) {
            var failMessage = "There was output in the browser console:" +
                              browserLog.map(JSON.stringify).join(";\n");
            callback.fail(failMessage);
        }
        else {
            callback();
        }
    });
});
```

You'll want to check out the documentation on [**After hooks**](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js#after-hooks), which are Cucumber's equivalent to Jasmine's `afterEach`.

Answer (score 1):

How @velochy stated there is now an own package for the module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-console-plugin

You can use it in your protractor.conf:

```
  plugins: [{
    package: 'protractor-console-plugin',
    failOnWarning: {Boolean}                (Default - false),
    failOnError: {Boolean}                  (Default - true),
    logWarnings: {Boolean}                  (Default - true),
    exclude: {Array of strings and regex}   (Default - [])
  }]
```