# How can i retrieve a value from console log and assert it in my Protractor test?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, assert, console.log

I want a function return the value which will be used for assertaion

Please consider the following function:

```
function giveWrittenValue(x) {
        var msg;
        x.getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
            if (value) {
                console.log(value);
                var errorMsg = $('.invalid.error-msg');
                errorMsg.isPresent().then(function (Present) {
                    if (Present) {
                        msg = errorMsg.getText();
                    }
                    else {
                        msg = 'Valid';
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                msg = 'No input is provided';
            }
            return msg;
        });
    }
```

and my code is here:

```
it('Provider VAT number validation with invalid VAT number',function () {
        ProviderVatNumber.sendKeys('IMEZ');
        element(by.tagName("body")).click();
        body.click();
        browser.sleep(3000);
        ccc = giveWrittenValue(ProviderVatNumber);
        expect(ccc).toBe('Invalid VAT number');  
});
```

I think there is some problem in the function.Please anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: can you please explain what you want exactly.. where you want to use console.log value?

Comment: I want to retrieve specific console log which is generated from my code. Based on the console log generated I want to check if my test is passed or failed @ Nikita

Comment: I would suggest finding a better way to test whatever functionality you are working on... that's not a realistic scenario to test for a production application.  If anything, instead of writing that value to console, just inject it into an HTML element and then check it exists there.

Comment: I updated my post with code. can you help on this? @Gunderson

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to grab the Console Logs and then perform an assert on them:

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
    // Replace the following with an Assert statement
    console.log('log: ' + require('util').inspect(browserLog));
    // expect(browserLog.length).toEqual(0);
});
```

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-get-hold-of-the-browsers-console

[Check there were no errors in the browser console with Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010647/check-there-were-no-errors-in-the-browser-console-with-protractor)

Comment: I updated my post with code. can you help on this? @John Stennett

Answer (score 0):

The way is the following:

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(consoleLogs) {
   // consoleLogs is an array of objects with level and message fields
   // for example in the level property you can also check if it's an error through level.value > 900
});
```

But the question is: why would you do that? It's actually a really unusual practice to test something displayed in the console (especially in e2e tests).
e2e tests should not test this stuff.

p.s. Keep in mind also that chrome provides the `assert` method that could be used for testing directly your logs:

```
console.assert(1 > 2, {"message":"1 it's not greater than 2"});
```

Comment: Hi, i Just updated my post with the code. Can you help on this ? @quirummo

Comment: First you need to return the value inside your giveWrittenValue function. Then when you call that you need to use then. All protractor methods return promises because they are asynchronous. Just fyi, I got the point that you changed your code and you updated all the question. But the right way to do that on SO is leaving the old question text and add an edited at the end with the new code. If you completely change your question, all the answers you got at the first question seem crazy if some user in the future will look at the question